# How to use Layout Inspector to inspect Notification View?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

Is it possible to inspect notifications list using Layout Inspector? I would like to check my `Notification` view parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

- Start emulator and expand status bar
- In Layout Inspector select
  process `com.android.systemui`

Now we have access to notification
views.

Comment: How to select systemui process? any menu items?